# how to return object data of multiple indexing without foreach in php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I fetch data of particular table by stored procedure  ,demo code is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11
                    [Code] => Item001
                    [Name] => Item
                    [Description] => Items
                    [DisplayName] => Items
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 
                    [DefaultNarration] => 
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-02 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-08 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12
                    [Code] => Uom001
                    [Name] => Uom
                    [Description] => Uom
                    [DisplayName] => Uom
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 1
                    [DefaultNarration] => 1
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-02 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-02 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 1
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 13
                    [Code] => Role
                    [Name] => Role
                    [Description] => Role
                    [DisplayName] => Role
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 1
                    [DefaultNarration] => 
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-03 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-03 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 14
                    [Code] => User
                    [Name] => User
                    [Description] => Use
                    [DisplayName] => User
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 1
                    [DefaultNarration] => 71
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-03 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-09 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 15
                    [Code] => AccountMaster
                    [Name] => AccountMaster
                    [Description] => AccountMaster
                    [DisplayName] => Account
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 1
                    [DefaultNarration] => 1
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-05 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-05 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [object_types] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 16
                    [Code] => Contact
                    [Name] => Contact
                    [Description] => Contact
                    [DisplayName] => Contact
                    [ObjectTypeIdentifier] => 1
                    [CheckPermissions] => 1
                    [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 103
                    [DefaultNarration] => 71
                    [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
                    [CreatedBy] => 1
                    [ModifiedBy] => 1
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-07 00:00:00
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-08 00:00:00
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 1
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I want to retrun all data without foreach looping statement.

```
$data = array();
            foreach($modelData as $row){
                $data[] = $row[$model->name];
            }
            return $data;
```

I didnt want to use this foreach loop. so please suggest me appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) function

do something like :

```
$data = array_map(function($model){
return $model['object_type']['Name'];
},$modelData);
```

the code is not tested, but it should be something like this

Based on what your var_dump response was to the other solution, try :

```
$data = array_map(function($model){
return $model['object_type']['Name']['text'];
},$modelData);
```

Comment: Not Getting Proper array because $model=??

Comment: Edited, please check now

Comment: Warning (2): array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members [APP\Plugin\Admin\Controller\ObjectTypesController.php, line 107]

Comment: updated, it was my mistake i put the parameters in the wrong order

Comment: Not getting proper object array

Comment: try now, something is weird based on what you provided and what you get from your var_dump to Kanishka response

Answer (score 0):

How about JSON? You can get a string from array.

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but in case it is, I tried doing the same thing, to get an array without the alias like: `$array['first_name']` instead of `$array['User']['first_name']` in order to print it in `JSON` format, but unfortunatelly there is no way to natively do that, so I sticked to the foreach

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 11
            [text] => Item
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 12
            [text] => Uom
        )
)I want to bind this object array to dropdown control so remove foreach stmt. by any kind of php function like array_map,etc.

Comment: if you are getting the data from `Model::find()`  use `find("list", $options)`.  Otherwise you will need a php_functnon, sorry man :(

Answer (score 0):

If not `foreach`, then try `for` because to iterate arrays you have to use some loops and the fastest is `for` as below

```
$data = array();
$size = sizeof($modelData);

for($i=0; $i<=$size; $i++)
{
    $data[] = $modelData[$i][$model->name];
}
return $data;
```

Comment: Describe your requirement.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 11
            [text] => Item
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 12
            [text] => Uom
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 13
            [text] => Role
        )
)

Comment: Sir ,I want to bind this data into dropdown control for that i didnt want to use foreach loop or any kind of loop stmt direct any php function

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  $final_array = array_map(
  function ($a) { 

    return  $a['object_types']['Name'];
  }, 
    $modelData
  );

 print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: Sir I want to form $data without for or any lopp..by direct any php function..because i done by foreach stmt.

Comment: Not getting my object array .. pls use my array variable name.

Comment: @Abhishek i updated my answer , now what is happening , is there any errors

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 11
            [text] => Item
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 12
            [text] => Uom
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 13
            [text] => Role
        )
)

Comment: I want to Add This array values to direct dropdown withou for stmt

Comment: @Abhishek is this your real array , do you need a key value array like array(11=>'Item',12=>'Uom',13=>'Role'); ?

Comment: No sir i did not change the array as u suggest .,Because i use sp for fetch data then save by using foreach stmt. so i want that foreach loop remove by any function.